# How can I name a python variable after a value?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe:

```
     X    Y
1   'a'  ('good','pretty')
2   'b'  ('bad','ugly')
3   'z'  ('ok','soso')
```

I need to create three different lists: a has good and pretty in different rows; b has bad and ugly in different rows and so on...

How can I do this by automatically taking values from column X to create those list variables?

here is the code:

```
list1 = ['good, pretty','a']
list2 = ['bad, ugly','b']
list3 = ['ok, soso','c']
test = pd.DataFrame([list1, list2, list3], columns=['desc', 'item'])
test
```

and the dataframe looks like:

```
           desc item
0  good, pretty    a
1     bad, ugly    b
2      ok, soso    c
```

I need the final lists to look like:

```
 {'a':     ('good','pretty'),
  'b':     ('bad','ugly'),
  'c':     ('ok','soso')}
```

Comment: Use a [dictionary](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-python)..?

Comment: it would be better if you can provide your code.

Comment: I have updated codes to get the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dictionary comprehension on a groupby.

```
>>> {idx: group['desc'].tolist() 
     for idx, group in test.groupby('item')}

{'a': ['good, pretty'], 'b': ['bad, ugly'], 'c': ['ok, soso']}
```

Comment: Thx Alexander, this works great to help convert my pandas dataframe to dictionary. But I do need to further split the dictionary into lists named after the keys. For example var_a, var_b, var_c will do. Is it possible?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that, because you could overwrite other existing variables or methods. It is common to keep the variables in a dictionary and access them that way.

Comment: I see. agree that from what I have tried that is so far the best option.